# matplotlib.pyplot.pause is too slow on small values

Tags: animation, matplotlib

I'd like to plot animation as dots one by one. My code is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[i, i] for i in range(100)]
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 100])
for point in data:
    plt.plot(point[0], point[1], 'o')
    plt.pause(1e-10)
plt.show()
```

But `pause(seconds)` seems to be unable to handle small fractions of a second. It waits for much longer than the argument I pass to it if the argument is tiny. Is there a way to make it work as desired?

I know that the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) says

> This can be used for crude animation. For more complex animation, see matplotlib.animation.
>   This function is experimental; its behaviour may be changed or extended in a future release.

Comment: The problem isn't with matplotlib, but with `1e-10`. I believe it is being rounded... I recommend a higher precision data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think perhaps you missed the most important part of the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) in relation to your question:

> If there is an active figure, it will be updated and displayed before
>   the pause, and the GUI event loop (if any) will run during the pause.

I'd imagine that the pause might well be around `1e-10` seconds, its just that the point has to be drawn onto the figure which is taking longer than that time interval.

Comment: If you'd like to achieve a faster animation effect you can skip plotting some points by using, for example, `for point in data[::5]` (which would plot every fifth value).